# EditText color is grey in Android Studio design editor

Tags: android, xml

I am seeing grey color of edit text in android studio design editor, can someone give me idea why is this ?

Note:
at the moment I cannot past actual screenshot because I am new to stackoverflow and have not more than 50 reputations to upload image. 
so image in link is just reference how grey color its showing with edit text. this is not actual screen shot. 
[Check image, this is rendering error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/te4nd.png)
and XML code for edit text is

```
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/discriptionLogo"
      android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
      android:hint="Discription"
      android:id="@+id/discription"
      android:textColor="@color/colorblack"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `CoordinatorLayout` in a wrong way which leads to the improper render. Correct it or simply replace the `CoordinatorLayout` with `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`. Your `EditText` has nothing to do with this error. Post your full xml file if you are not able to sort this out.

Comment: this image is just reference how grey color its showing with edit text. this is not actual screen shot.

Comment: at the moment I cannot past actual screenshot because I am new to stackoverflow and have not more than 50 reputations to upload image.
So use this image as reference